# What type of exterior coating will allow water vapor to pass through cinder block?

Tags: cinderblock

I was asked to paint an exterior of a cinder block chimney and need to find out what type of exterior coating will allow water vapor pass through the block so that it doesn't ruin it from the inside out.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: I reworded to try to make the question a technical question as opposed to a shopping question.

Answer (score 1):

Any "breathable" exterior coating will work.  The traditional one is limewash, others are silicate paint, or silane-siloxane sealer as mentioned by @LeeSam.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a silane-siloxane sealer. You need a sealer that is penetrating (will provide better uv protection) to keep water out, yet still be breathable.

This explains it better: https://www.masoncontractors.org/2016/11/25/benefits-of-silane-siloxane-sealer-for-older-brick-buildings/